# Adding to a variable in a timer

Tags: java, timer

I'm a beginner with java so sorry for the basic question. I'm trying to add 5 to a variable every minute, but I cannot manage to do it without a scope-problem or without the addition failing to work. How to fix this?

My code is:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainTimer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Timer sigMassTimer = new Timer();

        int sigMass;
        sigMass = 0;

        sigMassTimer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

            @Override
            public void run(){

                String invSigMass = "You have "+ (sigMass + 5) + " units.";
                System.out.println(invSigMass);
            }
        }, 1*60*1000, 1*60*1000);       
    }   
}
```

and I get "You have 5 units" as output every minute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `sigMass` declaration into the `TimerTask` (else wise you can only access it, if it is declared `final` and thus cannot be incremented with each invocation) **and** change the way you increment:

```
Timer sigMassTimer = new Timer();
sigMassTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    int sigMass = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sigMass += 5;
        String invSigMass = "You have " + sigMass + " units.";
        System.out.println(invSigMass);
    }
}, 1*60*1000, 1*60*1000);
// Output:
// You have 5 units.
// You have 10 units.
// You have 15 units.
// You have 20 units.
// You have 25 units.
```

Alternatively, you could also make `sigMass` a `static` member of your `MainTimer` class.

Answer (score 0):

`sigMass` is initialized to `0`, and you're just displaying `sigMass + 5`, that is `5` every minute instead of actually incrementing `5` to `sigMass`.

Try changing this bit:

```
String invSigMass = "You have "+ (sigMass + 5) + " units.";
```

to

```
sigMass = sigMass + 5;    
String invSigMass = "You have "+ sigMass + " units.";
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: Beside that, the `sigMass` declaration needs to be moved into the `TimerTask`
 class.

Comment: I have tried both suggestions; the first gives me a error because the local variable sigMass in enclosed scope must be final (no idea what that means). The second gives me an output of "You have 5 units" every minute, which was why I tried initiaizing it before the Override; I thought the value would otherwise be set to 0 every time. No idea whether that is correct.